# A word for: Someone who can never make time for you

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to find a word for someone who can never make time for you. Preferably with the connotation that the person could easily find the time if they wanted to.

Comment: By the way, in a single-word-request, you have to include an example sentence. It doesn't have to be too complicated but it helps to pinpoint how the word could be used.

Answer (score 0):

One might call such a person "**slippery**".  This sense of the word is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/slippery) as

> (of a person) evasive and unpredictable; not to be relied on.

Be aware that "slippery" may also bear connotations of dishonesty, however.

Answer (score 0):

You could say they are *avoiding* you or *[blowing you off](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blow%20off)* [TFD]

> blow someone or something off Sl. to ignore someone or something; to skip an appointment with someone; to not attend something where one is expected. He decided to sleep in and blow this class off. It wasn't right for you to just blow off an old friend the way you did.

Answer (score 0):

**Self-involved**. It's not quite as strong as **narcissistic** (though that would seem to apply as well). **Selfish** is a bit too broad.

Answer (score 0):

If the person has some obligation to make time for you (for example, a spouse or the parent of a minor child) the word would be **neglectful**. From [*Cambridge Dictionary*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/neglectful):

> **Neglectful, *adjective***
>   not giving enough care and attention to
>   something or someone:
>   *I'm sure my boss thinks I've been neglectful of
>   my duties recently.*

You can also use the verb and noun forms to describe the person's behavior. So:

> You're such a **neglectful** cat-person! You **neglected** me when I clearly
>   needed your attention, as evidenced by my walking across your keyboard
>   while you were typing, *and* you **neglected** to scratch my chin after I bit you for rubbing my tummy too often! If your **neglect** gets any more severe, Cat
>   Protective Services will be coming to take me away!

On the other hand, if there is not a pre-existing obligation (for example, with a casual friend or potential romantic partner), the correct phrase would be **not that into you**. You could convert it to a compound adjective if you really need an adjectival use, as in *he was one of those **not-that-into-me** boyfriends.*

Answer (score 0):

I'm having trouble finding a noun, but at least I found you an adjective.

***[Self-important](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/self-importance?q=self-important)***

> Self-importance: the belief that you are more important or valuable than other people

*(Cambridge Dictionary)*